# What is current standard practise for redirects of http sub/domains

Tags: dns

If I have widget.net domain, I assume users are going to type in either www.widget.net or widget.net and expect to get to the same place in either case. But taking that as a given which is best practise:

1. In either case browser shows the url they originally entered
2. If the user enters www.widget.net it should change to widget.net (widget.net remains unchanged)
3. If user enters widget.net it should change to www.widget.net (www.widget.net remains unchanged)

Also if have widget.com domain as well what should happen.

(I know how to do this now using Amazon Route53 and Amazon S3, just not what I should do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely want to have one "canonical" fqdn. Which one you choose is just personal preference but all of the other ones should redirect to the canonical domain to avoid duplicate content issues and visitor confusion.

Comment: I went with widget.net instead of www.widget.net , I do prefer its simplicity. Since found one problem with it though, my site was running off aws elastic beanstalk, with that you can use blue/green deployment to deploy  a new version with no downtime, you just set Route53 to point domain to the EB domain address and then within EB just use Swap Urls. But you have to point to EB domain address using CNAME and not allowed to do this from the apex, you can use an ALIAS to point to the load balancer serving the EB instance but then then you have to manually modify this every time do deployment